# Bluetooth Won't Turn On in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I'm using a ThinkPad 13 Gen 2 and Bluetooth won't turn on. Once I toggle the bluetooth toggle from settings, it'll work then when I change screen and come back it's off.
This is the result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; uname -r; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Output:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V [8086:15d8] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V [17aa:5063]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0451:8025 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c94 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0451:ca01 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1532:005c Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0451:8027 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 1b1c:1b15 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4.18.0-21-generic
[    0.028000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST: CPU0: -21639656 force to 0
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.004000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs within socket(s), fixing all errors
[    0.100022] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.905989] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x4d1f00)
[    9.625944] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.9f0a2d68.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.640894] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    9.653124] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[   10.589911] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   10.589923] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   10.589925] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   10.589926] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   10.589929] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.933976] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.933978] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.933980] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   31.523702] audit: type=1107 audit(1560246752.395:67): pid=975 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2518 label="snap.mailspring.mailspring" peer_pid=973 peer_label="unconfined"
[18446744056.005637] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: CPU0 0 --> -21895161. Restoring
```

Also bluez is latest 5.50

I appreciate your help everyone.

Thanks